# Degenerate subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

A null vector is a nonzero vector that is orthogonal to 
itself.
If W is a subspace of V,let $W^{\perp}$ = [$v{\in}$ W : $v{\perp}$W]. 
$W^{\perp}$ is a subspace of V called W perp.

A subspace W of V is called nondegenerate if g | W is nondegenerate. 
The nondegeneracy of g on the whole space V is equivalent to 
$v^{\perp}$ = 0.
A bilinear form on V is an 
**R**-bilinear function b:$V{\times}$ $V {\to}$ R,
and we consider only the symmetric ciase: 
b{v, w) = fo(w, v) for all v, w.
A symmetric bilinear form b on V is :
nondegenerate provided b{v, w) = 0 for all $w {\in}$V implies v=0.

A scalar product g on a vector space V is a nondegenerate 
symmetria bilinear form on V.

**How do I show the $v^{\perp}$ is a degenerate 
subspace if v is a null vector and the operator F:$v^{\perp}$${\to}$$v^{\perp}$?**

Comment: If you're working with linear spaces, **axioms** of inner product require that the *only* vector that is perpendicular to itself is the zero vector... and what are $\;g\,,\;\;g|W\;$ ? And in your definition of "scalar product", are you sure you don't have to require that $\;g\;$ is a **positive definite** bilinear form?? Otherwise it is going to contradict the most standard definitions... Check all this, as your question seems to be a little messy. Finally: your very last line doesn't seem to make much sense, either.